# Return unique elements in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I need help with below code

```
list1 = [[1],[1,2]]
```

should return `[1]`

```
list2 = [[2],[1,2]]
```

should return `[2]`

```
list3 = [[2],[1,2]]
```

should return `[2]`

```
list4 = [[3],[1,2]]
```

should return `[3,1]` (min of list)

I tried to create a function but couldn't expand with my basic coding skills

```
def UniqueItems(source, target):
    all = source + target
    return set(all)
```

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly.  I do not understand the logic that gets you from the input to the output in the given cases.  "Unique" does not seem to apply, as in the first few cases, you return the element that is common between the lists.  Returning the `min` does not seem to result from the concept of "unique".

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
array = [['a','b'], ['a', 'b','c'], ['a']]
result = set(x for l in array for x in l)
print(result)
```

Comment: This does not return OP's expected results as stated in the question.